# Flexbox: how make one item higher than the rest?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am building a page which has 8 items distributed over two rows using a flexbox container. Each item is 25% wide and 50% high. Because it is a horizontal scrolling page, I use px instead of % (values are generated by javascript based on the screen size). For this example I'm using a screen size of 1440px.

Now when I click on one of the items, it has to go to the very start, become twice as wide and twice as high.

It currently looks like this (ignore the blurry images please):
[Initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esv2z.jpg)

Making the items wider is no problem (using flex-basis: 720px), but when I make the first item higher (height 100%), the items that were previously on the second row are no longer visible. Instead they are pushed down because of the first image: [State when I make the first item bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nryrk.jpg)

What I actually want is that the smaller items are evenly distributed next to the bigger item. Is this possible?

This is my HTML markup (it contains web2py syntax, but there are 8 items in total):

```
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="flexcontainer">
     {{for s in stages:}}
        <div class="flexitem">
           <img src="{{=URL('default', 'download', args=s.image)}}" class="stage-img">
       </div>
     {{pass}}
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.flexcontainer {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3000px; /* Hardcoded width for testing purposes */
}

.flexcontainer .flexitem {
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: 360px;
    height: 50%;
}

.flexcontainer .flexitem img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Style for the active/clicked item */
.flexcontainer .flexitem.active {
    flex-basis: 720px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That's the expected behaviour so no, what you want isn't really possible without a great deal of HTML restructuring and, probably, javascript.

Comment: It is absolutely possible to achieve. But probably not with flexbox. And I'm not sure if pure CSS would the most efficient or is it better to use a js gallery library. Can you provide jsfiddle so we can experiment a bit?

Comment: @Paulie_D if i were to put the "active item" in a div which is next to the flexbox container, would that work?

Comment: It might...that's what I meant by restructuring the HTML